# Start ssh tunnel on server startup

Tags: centos, reboot

I am running Centos stream and everytime after I start my server I have to run this command line:

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9944:localhost:9922 localhost -N
```

After running this command, the OS will ask me to login as root (even if I am already logged as root) and everything works after that.

My problem: I want to add this code to a cronjob on reboot, something like:

@reboot root ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9944:localhost:9922 localhost -N

However it does not work. I think it is asking for the password but there is no one to type it (of course). So how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the cron logs?

Comment: @Turdie of course, nothing there.

Comment: Maybe try to create as systemd service https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/c0f9304deea566842490. And maybe try to setup the tunnel with an ssh key

Comment: it certainly sounds like your issue would be related to ssh expecting a password, set up keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this with cron. The best is to add a **systemd service**. For example, for the similar problem I use the unit file which looks like the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=forward public port 9944 to local 9922 with SSH
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=ssh -i /root/.ssh/forwarder -g -L 0.0.0.0:9944:localhost:9922 localhost -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -N
Restart=always
RestartSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save this as `/etc/systemd/system/ssh-forward-9944-to-9922.service` and execute

```
systemctl enable ssh-forward-9944-to-9922.service
systemctl start ssh-forward-9944-to-9922.service
```

Notice I added *exit on forward failure* option so if something claims that port the systemd will properly recognize this unit as failed. Notice also *global bind* option, to actually accept connections from other hosts, because despite your attempt to bind it to `0.0.0.0`, that will not work unless you enable it with `-g`.

Finally, you have to setup keys properly. The unit file above is constructed so that the ssh client will be run as root and it will connect to localhost as root which means you need to have `PermitRootLogin yes` or better, `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` (the default, the same thing as older spelling `without-password`) in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. The private key must be stored *unencrypted* as `/root/.ssh/forwarder`. The public key should go into `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

The best is to use a dedicated key, generate it with

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f /root/.ssh/forwarder
```

(hit `<Enter>` twice for no passprase). Then append the contents of the public counterpart to `authorized_keys` with

```
cat /root/.ssh/forwarder.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Edit `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` to restrict this key (the last line) heavily, similar to the following:

```
restrict,port-forwarding,command="/bin/false" ssh-ed25519 AA[key contents follows]7b localhost port forwarder
```

just add this `restrict,...` magic spell before your `ssh-ed25519 ...` in the last line. You may enhance it further, for example, add `from="127.0.0.1,::1",permitopen="127.0.0.1:9922",permitopen="[::1]:9922"` into restriction list (though I am not totally sure about correct spelling of IPv6 addresses in this file); read `man authorized_keys` for details about this.